# How do I get Nymgo working?

Tags: wine

I have installed [Nymgo](http://www.nymgo.com/) software on Ubuntu OS 11.10. Nymgo application crashes very often.
I have installed this using wine.

Could you tell me some methods to debug the actual cause of crashing of the application.  If there are no suggestions to get Nymgo's own client working, then please give the best alternatives that would work with this VoIP service.

Answer (score 1):

kindly note that nymgo isn't compatible with ubuntu thus it might crashes under virtual software like wine. However you can use any sip client that is compatible with your OS and configure it with our service. use ata.nymgo.com as the sip server.